# Converting Float to a String in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sometimes when I try to print a Float in rails, I get an error like this:

```
TypeError at /delivery_requests/33/edit
no implicit conversion of Float into String

on the line: 
= this_is_a_float
```

I know I can just add `.to_s` to the float, but why is this not done by default?

Comment: Why should it be done by default?

Answer (score 14):

This is because you're using a Float in place where a String is expected like the following example:

```
"Value = " + 1.2 # => no implicit conversion of Float into String
```

To fix this you must explicitly convert the Float into a String

```
"Value = " + 1.2.to_s # => Value = 1.2
```

Comment: So, is the reason that this is not done by default (like in Java where System.out.print can handle almost all datatypes) is because in Ruby, 1.2 could be interpreted as a function on 1?
But even then, couldn't Ruby try to do 1.2.to_s?

Comment: I don't know exactly why Ruby doesn't do it the same as Java.

Answer (score 4):

This post is old, so a little bit of an update for future readers.  Rather than doing `to_s` which works, you can simply do string interpolation. It's also faster and more memory efficient.

```
x = 0.005
"With string interpolation: #{x}"  # => "With string interpolation: 0.005"
"Standard to_s method: " + x.to_s  # => "Standard to_s method: 0.005"
```

You can also do directly (tho, admittedly silly):

```
"string interpolation: #{0.005}"  # => "string interpolation: 0.005"
```

String interpolation is the way to go in Rails apps, mostly if you're pulling in ActiveRecord objects' various datatypes. It'll automatically `.to_s` it for you properly, and you simply need to call it as `model.value` instead of `model.value.to_s`.